# UI communication colors

Tags: validation, user-interface, colors

I'm creating message boxes with different states. One for success, one for error.

I've using colors ala http://www.flickr.com/photos/jannejanne/2492207808/sizes/o/

But I came up with 2 colors too many. Blue and Yellow.

Does anyone know any good patterns/best practices for when to use these standard "Web 2.0" colors?

Thanks!

Comment: Im confused? Why not use only the green and the red? The green for success and the red for error? You don't have to use the blue and yellow just because Flickr uses them ...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it helps, but, I generally try and use colors that people are familiar with in real life:

Have a problem/issue?  Then Red.

Need Caution?  Then Yellow.

etc...

[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/topics/design/userinterfacedesign/) has some good content regarding User Interface Design in general that may help answer your questions.